# Any "singular/plural" Vs "a"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

should I use any with **singular** or **plural nouns** in the following context? And can I use a instead?

1. If you have **any complaints** with respect to **any programme(s)** on this channel, please inform us.
2. If you have **any complaint** with respect to **any programme(s)** on this channel, please inform us.
3. If you have **a complaint** with respect to **any programme(s)** on this channel, please inform us.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking that

> **any**

can be used with plural and singular, and

> **a**

is used with singular.